# Java Create SessionFactory from Properties file

Tags: java, hibernate

I am creating session factory by reading properties file which is outside from by project.
My Properties file is as follows,

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.username=root
hibernate.connection.password=root
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hi5
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
entity=CmtFreeformpages,CmtNewsTicker
```

I am creating Sessionfactory by reading the properties file as follows,

```
properties.load(new FileReader(new File(global.constants.GlobalConstants.parentDirectory + File.separator + global.constants.GlobalConstants.propertiesFile)));
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().setProperties(properties);
Set<Object> setOfProperties = properties.keySet();
for(Object propertyObject : setOfProperties){
if (propertyObject != null) {
String propName = propertyObject.toString();
if(propName.equalsIgnoreCase("entity")){
String value = properties.getProperty(propName);
Object[] entities = value.split(",");
for(int i=0;i<entities.length;i++){
 configuration.addAnnotatedClass(entities[i]);
}
sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
```

but configuration.addAnnotatedClass method is not accepting the string.So how to add the annotated classes to the configuration ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `addAnnotatedClass()` accepts a `Class`, you need to get `Class`es for the given class names using `Class.forName()`:

```
configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Class.forName(entities[i]));
```

Note that `Class.forName()` expects fully qualified class names, i.e. with package names included.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can add it to the configuration, you will have to load the named entity class with a classloader, using the package name and class name.

It might also be worthwhile to call addPackage as well, in case there are any annotations at the package level.